# How to properly start and cancel a task.

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to properly start a task and cancel it. I've changed my code to be more simple to understand my issue and pasted it below (I've also added some comments). The `SubscribeToReport` method is called first - it contains an await `runReportTask` which from my understanding will just start the `runReportTask` method, wait for it to complete execution, then resume executing the code that appear after the `await`.

Inside `runReportTask` I create a CancellationTokenSource and start a new task using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. Inside the task, there is a while loop that performs processing as long as the task hasn't been canceled. From my understanding, if `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` is ever true, the else within my while loop will run and the task will stop. After that, I expect `SubscribeToReport()` to continue execution - this does not happen, and it doesn't ever seem like my code does anything when I call `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` in `StopReportTask()` . What am I doing wrong? I've been at this for a while and I just can't seem to wrap my head around how this is supposed to work.

```
private async static void SubscribeToReport()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for task to finish or cancel...");

    await runReportTask();

    Console.WriteLine("Task has finished or was canceled."); // THIS LINE NEVER EXECUTES
}

private static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
private static CancellationToken cancellationToken;
private bool moreToDo = true;
private static Task runReportTask()
{
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Were we already canceled?
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        while(moreToDo == true)
        {
            if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Do important code here
            }
            else{
                Console.WriteLine("Task canceled."); // THIS LINE NEVER EXECUTES WHEN CALLING StopReportTask() below
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                break;
            }
        }

    }, cancellationToken);
}

// This method is called from another source file
private void StopReportTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stopping report task...");

    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm the `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is called on the same object?

Comment: The class the contains this code is a singleton, so yes.

Comment: I'm starting to think this may be an issue related to a nanomsg method I am using. I'm using nanomsg to receive data via a publisher/subscriber system - inside my while loop I have a method that listens for messages - it waits until it receives one - during this time I don't think the while loop continues running which would explain why the cancellation token isn't working. I've debugged my StopReportTask method and the cancellation token is definitely returning true (as in it wants to cancel the task).

Comment: _"The class the contains this code is a singleton"_ -- the relevant code and class field are `static`, so they are not part of a singleton. And given the code you posted, it is theoretically possible, if you call `runReportTask()` again before the first task finishes, that the first task will never be canceled. It is also true, as you observe, that if the code is blocked, it can never get to a point of detecting the cancellation. If you want a real answer, you need to post a real [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. There is not enough context here to know for sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 6):

> it contains an await runReportTask which from my understanding will just start the runReportTask method, wait for it to complete execution, then resume executing the code that appear after the await.

The code:

```
await runReportTask();
```

is like this code:

```
var task = runReportTask();
await task;
```

So, to be clear, it is the *method call* that starts the task running. `await` just (asynchronously) waits for it to complete.

It's also important to note that `await` is an *asynchronous* wait. This means it pauses the method's execution *and returns*. So, as far as your calling code knows, `SubscribeToReport` has completed executing.

(This is one of the [problems of `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); it's not easily consumable - calling code doesn't know when it completes).

> Inside runReportTask I create a CancellationTokenSource and start a new task using Task.Factory.StartNew().

As a side note, you should use `Task.Run`. [`Task.Factory.StartNew` is a low-level API with dangerous default settings](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

> it doesn't ever seem like my code does anything when I call cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() in StopReportTask()

It's probably a different `cancellationTokenSource` instance.

You could try this, as a test - I'm not sure if it's your desired semantics, though (it will cause `runReportTask` to cancel the previous attempt):

```
private static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
private static readonly object _mutex = new object();
private bool moreToDo = true;
private static Task runReportTask()
{
  CancellationTokenSource oldCts, currentCts;
  lock (_mutex)
  {
    oldCts = cancellationTokenSource;
    currentCts = cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  }
  if (oldCts != null)
    oldCts.Cancel();
  var cancellationToken = currentCts.Token;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Something that bit me recently is that await doesn't always "pause execution and return". Its possible to have a method that returns a `Task` yet always runs synchronously. Even stranger, I've seen a task that writes to a network stream be executed synchronously, not yielding control back to the caller (assuming the write was very small).

Comment: @YarekT: [`await` first checks if its awaitable has completed; if it has, then it continues executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: I have a `TcpClient`'s `NetworkStream` that I `WriteAsync` to, that, even though it seems like it should be async, often runs synchronously, in the same thread as the caller. It may be that the write just completes really really fast, I don't know. I now always wrap tasks that I don't immediatly await in a Task.Run.

Comment: @YarekT: Network writes complete after copying the data to a system buffer (if there is buffer space available). So it's normal for them to complete synchronously. `Task.Run` shouldn't be necessary since copying memory buffers is extremely fast.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a typing error, but `moreToDo` is not static. Your static function `RunReportTask` can't access it. Besides it seems that you want that others outside your `runReportTask` can change `moreToDo` to stop this task. Are you sure you want this?

If you want others to stop your task, why don't you let them use the CancellationTokenSource?

On the other hand, if you only want that your `RunReportTask` is the only one who changes `moreToDo`, why did you make it accessible by others?

Having said that, I'm really not sure if it is wise to make your procedures static. Do you really plan to let someone start your process and let someone else stop this process?

Another problem is that if several starters start your task the `CancellationTokenSource` is replaced by a new one, while already running tasks still check the token created by your old `CancellationTokenSource`, and no one could stop the old running tasks. Are you sure this is what you intended?

These problems would not arise if you forced the task starter to provide the `CancellationTokenSource`, which is much more like MSDN proposes in the article [Cancellation in managed threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you'd let the starter of a task create the CancellationTokenSource, you would have an owner of the running task who could decide whether is should share the ownership or not. Others can't stop this task without consent of the task owner.

Because your SubscribeToReport returns void and not `Task` I assume it is a simplified version of an event handler. If not, I advise you to let it return Task.

The non-static version of your `SubscribeToReport` would be like this:

```
public async Task SubscribeToReport(CancellationToken token)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for task to finish or cancel...");
    await Task.Run(runReportTask(token), token);
    Console.WriteLine("Task has finished or was canceled.");
}

private Task runReportTask(CancellationToken token)
{
    bool moreToDo = false;
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    while(moreToDo && !token.IsCancellatinRequested)
    {
        // Do important code here, 
        // if this takes some time, make sure that 
        // you reqularly check IsCancellationRequested
        // this part runs until !moreToDo
     }

     if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Task canceled."); 
         // do cleanup here
     }
}
```

As an alternative: don't check for `token.IsCancellationRequested`, but call token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested. Be sure to do cleanup in finally statements.

usage:

```
using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    var token = CancellationTokenSource.Token;
    var task = SubscribeToReport(token);
    // here you are free to do other things,
    // if you decide to cancel:
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    // or:
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    
    // if you have nothing else to do but wait for the task to be completed
    // or cancelled:
    await task;
    ProcessTaskResult(task);
}
```

Note that the CancellationTokenSource is neatly disposed when your task is finished. The designer of the CancellationTokenSource implemented IDisposable to encourage you to free the resources it takes as soon as you don't need them anymore before the garbage collector does this.